# Windows 10 boot up issue

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, reboot

I have been facing a weird issue where, when I start up my Windows PC, nothing appears on my screen after the Windows 10 logo. Then, after about half to 1 minute, the system reboots and everything works fine.
This happens only sometimes, though. What could be the cause for this issue?

I tried reinstalling Windows as well unplugging all wires from the motherboard and connecting them back together.

PC specs:

- desktop
- motherboard - gigabyte b150m d3h,
- core i5-6500,
- gtx 1070,
- 16 GB RAM

**UPDATE:**

I don't remember precisely, but I think it started when I installed Linux alongside Windows 10 on a separate drive. But I removed Linux now, and I reinstalled Windows 10 too, and the issue persists.

Comment: Laptop or desktop? Have you updated Windows or any drivers/software just before this issue started?

Comment: @freginold Desktop. I don't remember precisely, but i think it started when I installed linux alongside windows 10 on separate drive. But I removed linux now, and i reinstalled windows 10 too and the issue persists

Comment: When the reboot happens, does it always reboot just one time, then run fine?  Does it ever reboot multiple times in a row?

Comment: @freginold I don't necessarily need to wait for reboot either, I can just turn it off by holding the power button, but the 2nd time it has always booted up fine so far

Comment: How often does it happen? Half the time you boot up?

Comment: @freginold once out of 3 or 4 times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like an issue that occurs when *hiberfil.sys* or the root C: directory appears to Windows OS to be altered during Linux operation.

Be sure to disable [Windows Quick Start](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-turn-off-fast-startup-windows-10-a.html) and to disable *Hibernate* before booting to Linux.

Save the following as a .bat file and run as Administrator to turn hibernation off and then shut down:

> powercfg -h off
>
> shutdown /s /t 0

Comment: Ah I see, thanks you very much! Hopefully this will work.
I was worried that it could be a hardware problem.

Comment: Le me know if it helps... BTW, the same script but with "off" changed to "on" can be used to enable *Hibernate* and then shut down.

Comment: I started using this script to turn off pc everytime, so far so good. But its possible it might just be by luck (because I have had days when it didn't occur at all). Thanks for help!